# Como faço para criar uma biblioteca no Android Studio e publicá-la

Tags: java, android, android-studio, library

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar uma biblioteca no Android Studio e posteriormente publicá-la em um repositório e adicionar suas dependências em um projeto.
Algo como por exemplo:

```
implementation 'br.com.luansilveira:teste:1.0.0'
```

Gostaria de saber também quais são os repositórios existentes e se há algum repositório free ou open-source.

Comment: Tem o site https://jitpack.io/

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário.
Ficaria satisfeito se você tivesse respondido a pergunta ao invés de comentar.